# Non recursive Kosaraju's two pass algorithm implementation taking forever to execute on a large data set

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, graph-algorithm, kosaraju-algorithm

- I coded this for an assignment which has passed its deadline.
- This implementation works completely fine with various smaller test cases and displays the sizes of the 5 largest Strongly Connected Components in the graph as it should.
- But seems to execute forever when i run it on the assignment data set of about 875714 vertices. (Doesn't even come out of the first DFS pass after 60mins)
- I've used the non recursive stack implementation of the DFS routine as i heard that the large number of vertices was causing recursion stack overflow problems.
- It would be really helpful if anyone could point out, what in this code is making it behave this way with the large dataset.
- The input file consists of list of edges in the graph. one edge/line.

(eg):

1 2

2 3

3 1

3 4

5 4

[Download link for the Large graph test case zip file](http://spark-public.s3.amazonaws.com/algo1/programming_prob/SCC.zip)

[Link to my program file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6kLAKFKEzAcajJFejN3MzlSaFU)

### Code follows:

//Macro definitions and Global variables

```
#define N 875714
#define all(a) (a).begin(), (a).end()
#define tr(c,i) for(typeof((c).begin()) i = (c).begin(); i != (c).end(); i++)

vi v(N), ft, size;
```

//Non recursive DFS algorithm

```
void DFS(vvi g, int s, int flag)
{
stack<int> stk;
stk.push(s);
v[s] = 1;

int jumpOut, count;
vi::iterator i;

if(flag == 2)
     count = 1;

while(!stk.empty())
{
i = g[stk.top()].begin();
jumpOut = 0;

for(; i != g[stk.top()].end(); i++)
{
    if(v[*i] != 1)
    {
        stk.push(*i);
        v[*i] = 1;

        if(flag == 2) //Count the SCC size
            count++;

        jumpOut = 1; //Jump to the while loop's beginning
        break;
    }
 }

 if(flag == 1 && jumpOut == 0) //Record the finishing time order of vertices
    ft.push_back(stk.top());

 if(jumpOut == 0)
      stk.pop();
}

if(flag == 2)
    size.push_back(count); //Store the SCC size
}
```

// The 2 pass Kosaraju algorithm

```
void kosaraju(vvi g, vvi gr)
{
cout<<"\nInside pass 1\n";

for(int i = N - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    if(v[i] != 1)
        DFS(gr, i, 1);

cout<<"\nPass 1 completed\n";

fill(all(v), 0);

cout<<"\nInside pass 2\n";

for(int i = N - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    if(v[ ft[i] ] != 1)
        DFS(g, ft[i], 2);

cout<<"\nPass 2 completed\n";
}
```

.

```
int main()
{
vvi g(N), gr(N);
ifstream file("/home/tauseef/Desktop/DAA/SCC.txt");
int first, second;
string line;

while(getline(file,line,'\n')) //Reading from file
{
    stringstream ss(line);
    ss >> first;
    ss >> second;
    if(first == second) //Eliminating self loops
        continue;

    g[first-1].push_back(second-1); //Creating G & Grev
    gr[second-1].push_back(first-1);
}

cout<<"\nfile read successfully\n";

kosaraju(g, gr);

cout<<"\nFinishing order is: ";
tr(ft, j)
    cout<<*j+1<<" ";
cout<<"\n";

sort(size.rbegin(), size.rend()); //Sorting the SCC sizes in descending order

cout<<"\nThe largest 5 SCCs are: ";
tr(size, j)
    cout<<*j<<" ";
cout<<"\n";

file.close();
}
```

Comment: How many edges does your graph have?

Comment: About 5105042 edges @sudomakeinstall2

Comment: Could you upload your graph somewhere?

Comment: Have attached the Zip file link under the sample input. @sudomakeinstall2

Comment: Please upload your code too, I made a few changes and it ran quickly. I want to be sure.

Comment: Have attached the link to my program file under the Test case download link. That's great! what changes did the trick? @sudomakeinstall2

Comment: This may seem to be a bit stupid and unhelpful, but from what I've looked at `jumpOut` can be of type `bool`.

Comment: Well, i was previously using goto: to skip to the while loop's beginning @FlareCat. Then because of this general taboo towards using goto i made a quick switch to this jumpOut flag. it doesn't matter that much :)

Comment: @sudomakeinstall2 it would be really helpful if you could share what changes you made to the code, fixed it. Please.

Comment: @Tauseef From what I've read in my text book, goto is not looked highly upon, so good job in getting rid of it.

Comment: IKR FlareCat Thank You :D
@sudomakeinstall2 please let me know how you fixed it. It would be of immense help to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several improvements that you can apply:
**1- `cin` is not as fast `scanf` for large inputs**: Because your input file is huge you better use `scanf` to read your data.
**2- It is not a good idea to pass large data to functions by value**: You have two huge graphs in your code that you pass them to functions by value. It takes a lot of time because every time you are making a copy of the data.
**3- There is no need to use `iterator` for traversing a `vector`**: Because you are using a `vector` and you have random access to it via `[]` operator there is no need to use `iterator` to access data.
**4- Your DFS is not efficient**: This is the most important one. Every time the program go to the beginning of the `while` and check the adjacency list of the element on top of the `stack` you start from the beginning and check elements. This make the algorithm very inefficient because you are checking some things over and over again. You can simply store how many of the children you have checked and when you go back to this element you start from the next element instead of starting from start.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<stack>
#include<algorithm>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include<sstream>
using namespace std;

typedef vector<int> vi;
typedef vector<vi> vvi;

#define N 875714
#define sz(a) int((a).size())
#define all(a) (a).begin(), (a).end()
#define tr(c,i) for(typeof((c).begin()) i = (c).begin(); i != (c).end(); i++)

vi v(N), ft, size;
vi childsVisited(N);

void DFS(vvi &g, int s, int flag)
{
    stack<int> stk;
    stk.push(s);
    v[s] = 1;

    int jumpOut, count;

    if(flag == 2)
        count = 1;
    int counter = 0;
    while(!stk.empty())
    {
        jumpOut = 0;
        int cur = stk.top();
        for ( ;childsVisited[cur] < g[cur].size(); ++childsVisited[cur] )
        //for ( int i=0; i< g[cur].size(); ++i )
        //for(; i != g[stk.top()].end(); i++)
        {
            int i = childsVisited[cur];
            int next = g[cur][i];
            if(v[next] != 1)
            {
                stk.push(next);
                v[next] = 1;
                if(flag == 2) //Count the SCC size
                    count++;

                jumpOut = 1; //Jump to the while loop's beginning
                break;
            }
        }

        if(flag == 1 && jumpOut == 0) //Record the finishing time order of vertices
            ft.push_back(stk.top());

        if(jumpOut == 0)
            stk.pop();
    }

    if(flag == 2)
        size.push_back(count); //Store the SCC size
}

void kosaraju(vvi &g, vvi &gr)
{
    cout<<"\nInside pass 1\n";

    for(int i = N - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        if(v[i] != 1)
            DFS(gr, i, 1);

    cout<<"\nPass 1 completed\n";

    fill(all(v), 0);
    fill(all(childsVisited), 0);

    cout<<"\nInside pass 2\n";

    for(int i = N - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        if(v[ ft[i] ] != 1)
            DFS(g, ft[i], 2);

    cout<<"\nPass 2 completed\n";
}

int main()
{
    freopen("input.txt","r",stdin);
    vvi g(N), gr(N);
    //ifstream file("/home/tauseef/Desktop/DAA/SCC.txt");
    int first, second;
    //string line;
    unsigned long int cnt = 0;

    //while(getline(file,line,'\n')) //Reading from file
    //{
        //stringstream ss(line);
        //ss >> first;
        //ss >> second;
        //if(first == second) //Eliminating self loops
            //continue;
    for ( int i = 0; i < 5105043; ++i ){
        int first, second;
        scanf("%d %d",&first,&second);
        g[first-1].push_back(second-1); //Creating G & Grev
        gr[second-1].push_back(first-1);
    }
        //cnt++;
    //}

    cout<<"\nfile read successfully\n";


    kosaraju(g, gr);

    cout<<"\nFinishing order is: ";

    sort(size.rbegin(), size.rend()); //Sorting the SCC sizes in descending order

    cout<<"\nThe largest 5 SCCs are: ";

}
```

Comment: Tweaking the DFS with that childsVisited(N) vector did the trick. 

There's still a minor bug with the code though.
lets call childsVisited(N) as CV(N).

Since CV is declared globally, the second DFS call produces incorrect values because of values in CV from the first DFS call.

When i tried to declare CV locally inside DFS() the execution again went back to running  for ever on large graphs and didn't terminate.

instead when i reinitialized CV to all zeroes after the first DFS call, the code worked fine.

What might be the reason for this abnormalcy while declaring CV locally inside DFS() ?

Comment: Just to clarify, do you mean to pass it by reference? Just curious.

Comment: Are you asking about the "passing by value" in his answer (or) about "declaring childsVisited locally" in my comment? @FlareCat

Comment: approve the edit, so that I can mark it as the answer @sudomakeinstall2 :)

Comment: @Tauseef the passing by value.

Comment: @Tauseef done. By the way in programming contests people usually use `arrays` and `memset` instead of `vector` and `fill`. It is a lot faster.

Comment: Ok @sudomakeinstall2 . But arrays require size while declaring right?
What to do when i'm unsure of how long the container is going to be?

Comment: @FlareCat, yes he means to pass the graphs by reference :)